# accordation menu without accordation effect in this specific case

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Inside my asp.net mvc application I have vertical menu

MENU ONE

- submenu item 1
- submenu item 2

MENU TWO

- submenu item 1
- submenu item 2

This menu using jquery accordation effect and initially is set as

```
MENU ONE
MENU TWO
```

where clicking on MENU ONE or MENU TWO will unwrap menu items. From my controller I'm sending to the view which menu should be unwrapped on specific page, and this is fine. I'm looking for solution to disable accordation animation if menu is already unwrapped.

For example: user was navigate to MENU TWO page, controller sends flag which will unwrap MENU TWO items. User now choose to open submenu item2 and accordation effect should not be applied. How to disable this accordation effect?

Here's the code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $.easing.def = "easeOutBounce";
            var menus = $('div.menu ul li.menu-title'),
                    current_submenu = null;
            menus.next().hide();
            menus.each(function (i) {
                var dropdown = $(this).next(),
                        title = $('a.title', this);
                title.click(function (e) {
                    if (current_submenu !== null && current_submenu !== dropdown) {
                        current_submenu.slideUp('slow');
                    }
                    current_submenu = dropdown;
                    dropdown.stop(false, true).slideToggle('slow');
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
                if (i == @ViewBag.OpenSubmenu)
                    title.click();
            });
        });
```

This `@ViewBag.OpenSubmenu` is integer which specifies which menu should be unwrapped 0 or 1 in this case.

Comment: A fiddle would be very nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've not used your code directly, but I believe I have the functionality in this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/gMAXt/).

You can control it just by clicking on the labels, or you can control it by calling a function that will open any one of the labels.

```
$('.title').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings( 'div' ).toggle( "slide" );
});

opensesame(3);

function opensesame (divnum)
{
    $(' .holder:nth-child('+ divnum +') ').children( 'div:not( :nth-child(1) )' ).toggle( 'slide' );
}
```

Perhaps it will give you some ideas.

Comment: ok, thank for your time. Having you're code in mind how can this opensesame function can open menu but without any effect? Effect should be present on THREE label.

Comment: That is correct. If you look at the fiddle, only the third submenu is open. If you change the number to 2, the second submenu opens. The same for 1. You can write a similar function, and when you meet certain criteria "If my first menu is open I don't want to do anything" you would pass a "0" to theh function. "if my first menu is closed, I'll open the second one" you would pass a "2" to the function. It allows you to open or close any of your menus under any 'if' condition. In terms of shutting off any operation just disable "click" on the menu.

Comment: Here is a fiddle where you can deactive or 'unbind' a click even on any element - http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/4EsFN/.